# How to get rid of a UISwitch when changing scenes

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, switch-statement, uiswitch

I am using a UISwitch in in the menu of a Cocos2d game I am making.

After the scene is changed (the user clicks any button and goes to a different scene/layer the switches are still on the screen

I have tried setting `switch1 = nil;` and `switch2 = nil;`in my dealloc but that doesn't work.  How would I do this?

Edit: Also tried `[switch1 release]`; which didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally remove controls from a view with:

```
[switch1 removeFromSuperview];
```

If you have any strong references to that control elsewhere, you can then do the appropriate memory management to release the switch at that point (e.g. setting it to `nil` or releasing it, as appropriate). You'd have to tell us about how it's defined (`strong` or `weak`, property or ivar, `IBOutlet` or programmatically created, etc.) for us to provide counsel there, but you probably have that covered.